# Upgrading from a non-genuine Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, license-key

I bought a "copy" of Windows 7 Ultimate from overseas that turned out to not be genuine.

Without having to reinstall, can I purchase Windows 7 Professional and authorize my current windows 7 Ultimate install? When I enter my new product key, will Windows 7 know it's a Professional key and disable the ultimate features (which I never use)?

I'm looking for a solution that means I don't have to spend the extra money for Windows 7 Ultimate without having to go through a reinstall.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

CV

Comment: Your best bet is to talk to Microsoft directly about this. They'd be interested to know where you bought the non-genuine Windows 7 and could probably tell you more about the process of switching to the genuine Windows 7 Professional. However, downgrading is **not** possible, you can only upgrade to a better SKU version (in your case there's nothing above Ultimate, so you're out of luck). Either way, contact Microsoft, they're the ones that could probably help you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially No - you can't "downgrade" as Ultimate is at the top of the chain.

If you really don't want to clean format there are work arounds, for example:

- [unawave.de](http://www.unawave.de/installation/downgrade-en.html?lang=EN)

**Update:**

With the rush to upgrade Windows 7 RC due to it expiring in March 2010, there are some new guides that can help achieve a "downgrade", here is one on [Icrontic](http://tech.icrontic.com/articles/upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-retail).